# what are pros and cons of an air handler located in cooled space?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

The air handler unit on my central air conditioning system in Florida is located in a closet that opens to the attic. The air handler is exposed to the attic temperatures (hot) which seems counter intuitive for maximum cooling capability. The cooling coils are bolted to a metal frame that's as hot as the attic.

Should I insulate the closet so the majority of the indoor unit is, truly in cooled indoor space?

What are the pros and cons of my current (typical) setup versus an indoor air handler that resides in the cooled space?

Comment: Are your ducts in said vented attic as well?

Comment: Do you have a strip heater in the air handler?  Is there one main return?

Comment: yes to both. Ducts are insulated from top of air handler to each room via attic. There is only 1 return air intake located immediately below the air handler. Indoor air returns through intake vent near floor then goes vertically through air handler, across cooling coils, out the top into cooling ducts.

Comment: @MarcCompere -- how much insulation is around the ducts?

Comment: I've got standard insulated air ducts. Some 4-inch. Some 6-inch with plenty of pink and older style dark grey fiberglass insulation on the tops of the rooms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same arrangement as in all 270 houses in my tract development in Dallas TX. It is the standard arrangement. There is some insulation on the inside of the sheetmetal panels.

EDIT Given the new info that this is a heat pump it would be some benefit to put an insulated ceiling on the closet. Possibly the original heating was a gas fired furnace and the heat pump a retrofit.

EDIT2 If there is a gas fired water heater in this closet,then it is probably necessary to have an opening for combustion air or to expel heat to the attic.

EDIT3 Our closet has an insulated drywall ceiling with one small section of screening to supply combustion air from the attic to the gas fired furnace and the gas fired water heater.

Comment: leave it alone is not a useful answer. it seems that an HVAC unit would deliver more cooling to the air if it didn't have to cool the metal frame exposed to hot attic temperatures

Comment: Do you have a gas furnace in the same unit? If so, does it get its combustion air from the closet or from outside?

Comment: In Dallas TX many houses have the air handler with refrigeration coils in the attic, not just in a closet connected to the attic.

Comment: mines a heat pump. no gas furnace.

Comment: it works great now. No complaints. But there's a penalty for heating coils that could otherwise remain significantly cooler. Surely I'm not the first to wonder about this

Comment: So there is no need to have the closet connected to the attic and you could seal and insulate any existing connection.

Comment: @MarcCompere be aware that some of the heat in that closet that you're worried about may be helping prevent the coils from freezing over which would render the AC useless until they've been defrosted.

Comment: Additionally, "leave it alone" can be a perfectly good and valid answer if there's nothing to worry about and no changes should be made to a professionally installed system that was installed according to the manufacturer's directions and all current conventional wisdom.

Comment: @JimStewart, the edit #1 is helpful. the house was built in 1957 and has no gas supply. the gas line run is too far to make sense and the local provider won't run the line. I'm not sure how heating was done originally. Probably electric. But the heat pump is within the last 10 years. Insulating the closet top sure makes a lot of sense as long as coils don't freeze. I can't figure out why closet tops with heat pumps aren't all insulated. Maybe just additional cost for marginal cooling improvement.  (???)

Comment: exhaust for gas fired heating would certainly need venting. this unit has no gas and nothing with combustion

Comment: Is there no ceiling at all in this closet? Is it just open to the attic?

Comment: yes, wide open to the attic. I think it's pretty typical but that doesn't mean it's smart. It has occured to me that measuring temperature differential between exiting coil air temperature and air temperature leaving ducts (entering the house) would be one way to monitor any closet insulation effects. I'll set this up.

Comment: A lot of work to do this. My guess is no measurable effect would be seen. Presumably the walls of the closet are not insulated so installing an insulated ceiling would greatly reduce heat flow through the walls of the closet. Measurement of air temp in duct might not reveal this, but if you keep the thermostat setting the same your ele usage should decline somewhat.